# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update city table as City + #p + 'Number of players of Team'+ #g + 'Number of Goals' but there is a solution including IN and EXISTS operators which do not solve my problem.

```
UPDATE Team set City = City +'#p'+ CONVERT(nvarchar(10),(select COUNT(p1.PlayerID) 
                                            from  Team as t     
                                            inner join PlayerTeam as pt on pt.TeamID= t.TeamID
                                            inner join Player as p1 on p1.PlayerID= pt.PlayerID
                                            where pt.Season = '13-14' 
                                            group by t.Name) )

                                            + '#g' +

                                            CONVERT(nvarchar(10),(select Count(g.PlayerID) 
                                            from  Team as t 
                                            inner join PlayerTeam as pt on pt.TeamID = t.TeamID
                                            inner join Player as p1 on p1.PlayerID= pt.PlayerID
                                            inner join Goals as g on g.PlayerID = p1.PlayerID
                                            where pt.Season = '13-14'
                                            group by t.Name))
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The intention of your code is hard to follow.

Comment: The error is *literally* telling you the problem here.

Comment: since you group by Name you have multilpe counts as the error indicates

Comment: “İstanbul #p25 #g74” output example is like that. For example team is Besiktas and desired output is its cityName#p(numberOfPlayers)#g(numberOfGoalsScored).

Comment: @apomene when i erase that aggregation, total number of players and goals are initiliazing to the City attribute of Team Table.

Comment: Aside: If `Player.PlayerId` is unique (and it really should be if it is named that), you don't need to join on Player in either of those subqueries. `join Goals as g on g.PlayerID = pt.PlayerID` is a valid join

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server I think the following would work:

```
UPDATE Team
SET City = t.City + city.City
FROM Team as T
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT t.TeamId, '#p' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), COUNT(p1.PlayerId)) + '#g' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), pg.Goals) AS City
        FROM Team as t
            INNER JOIN 
                PlayerTeam as pt on pt.TeamID= t.TeamID
            INNER JOIN 
                Player as p1 on p1.PlayerID = pt.PlayerID
            INNER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT g.PlayerID, COUNT(g.PlayerID) AS Goals 
                FROM  Team as t 
                INNER JOIN 
                    PlayerTeam as pt on pt.TeamID = t.TeamID
                INNER JOIN 
                    Player as p1 on p1.PlayerID= pt.PlayerID
                INNER JOIN 
                    Goals as g on g.PlayerID = p1.PlayerID
                WHERE pt.Season = '13-14'
                GROUP BY g.PlayerID, t.Name
            ) pg
            ON p1.PlayerID = pg.PlayerID
        WHERE pt.Season = '13-14'
        GROUP BY t.TeamId, p1.PlayerId, t.Name, pg.Goals
    ) city
    ON t.TeamID = city.TeamID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subqueries are trying to use a result set that includes *every* teams counts for *each* row of the update, which is meaningless, hence the error. You need use the ID of the row being updated.

```
UPDATE Team
SET City = T.City + '#p' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), COUNT(DISTINCT pt.PlayerId)) + '#g' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), COUNT(pt.PlayerId))
FROM Team as T
INNER JOIN PlayerTeam as PT ON PT.TeamID = T.TeamID AND PT.Season = '13-14' 
INNER JOIN Goals as G ON G.PlayerId = PT.PlayerId
```